# Ruby regex: exclude apostrophe but include it if it's escaped

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a ruby regex in order to extract some data from a long string (HTML source code).

From the below string I want to keep the four numbers (1, 11, 30, 90) and the first single quoted string (blablabla)

```
AjouterRDV(1, 11, 30, 90, 'blablabla', '123' ... (it goes on) );
```

My regex currently works with the above example, but fails when the string contains an escaped apostrophe, like in

```
AjouterRDV(1, 11, 30, 90, 'it\'s failing!', '123' ... (it goes on) );
```

Here is my regex with two example string (one passing and the other one failing) - [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/svmuTINl5d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way (assumes you don't need to match anything past your captures):

```
AjouterRDV\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),'(.+?)',
```

See [Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/gRNc5Sy0wS)

Comment: @ldavin the last bit `'(.+?)',` selects the `'` then `.+?` selects everything up to the _next_ combination of `',` that it finds. The `?` means that the selection is 'non-greedy' ie it will stop the first time it encounters `',`. If you were to remove the `?` it would become 'greedy' and select everything until the last time it encounters `',`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: -

```
/AjouterRDV\( (\d+), (\d+), (\d+), (\d+), '((?:(?<=\\)[']|[^'])*)', .* \);$/ix
```

`'((?:(?<=\\)[']|[^'])*)'` matches `'` preceded by `\`, or matches any character except `'`

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, there was just a comment by someone, but it seems he deleted it. His proposal was

```
AjouterRDV\( (\d+), (\d+), (\d+), (\d+), '((?<=\\)[']|[^'])*', .* \);$
```

which almost works, except for the fact that it doesn't capture the 5th group correctly. For that you need:

```
AjouterRDV\( (\d+), (\d+), (\d+), (\d+), '((?:(?<=\\)[']|[^'])*)', .* \);$
```

which converts his 'outer' group to a non-capturing group and then captures the selection within the single quotes.

Comment: Yep I was actually commenting his answer about the fifth element containing only the last letter of the string.
Thanks a lot